# Algebraic Formula to find order of non negative real numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

1. Given a set of $C$ ordered numbers ($C>10$, $C$ is some known even constant).
2. All but 2 consecutive numbers are 0.
3. The remaining 2 non zero consecutive positive real numbers (ordered pair, $a$ and $a^-$ are such that $a + a^- = 1$.
4. We don't know the positions of $a$ and $a^-$ in $C$.

Given any instance of $C$ develop an algebraic formula such that, the formula outputs the *"ordering information of the size two non negative numbers"* depending on if $a>a^-$ or $a<a^-$. There can be many ways to do this. For example:

1. If $a>a^-$ output 1 and if $a<a^-$  output -1 or 0.

Essentially we need to get the information about the order of the size of 2 without knowing their position or values.

I have been struggling a lot with this problem without any success but the problem seems tantalizingly 'obvious'. Anyone please ?

Comment: Just to confirm what you mean by consecutive-- the sequence $(0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, \pi + 2, \sqrt{17}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$ is valid but the sequence $(0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$ is not, right?

Comment: yes. exactly...

Comment: Something like
$$\mathrm{sgn}(a-a^{-})=\frac{|a-a^{-}|}{a-a^{-}}=\frac{\sqrt{(a-a^{-})^2}}{a-a^{-}}$$
Anyway you should be more clear on what you mean by algebraic formula. What should be the inputs? What are the allowed operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about
$$
x_1x_2(x_1-x_2) + x_2x_3(x_2-x_3) + \ldots + x_{C}x_{C-1}(x_C - x_{X-1})?
$$

Only one term will be non-zero and then the total will be positive if and only if the higher term is on the left.

Comment: yes logically that is fine but the resultant value would vary with the change in the non zero real numbers.. and it won't give the output value of $a$ and $a^-$ either.. I was looking something that acts as a flag (1/-1 as I mentioned above) or the original values themselves..

Comment: ok, then take $\text{sign}(x_1x_2(x_1-x_2) + x_2x_3(x_2-x_3) + \ldots + x_{C}x_{C-1}(x_C - x_{X-1}))$

Comment: I don't know how we implement the sign mathematically.. its more of a logical operation..

Comment: @TheoryQuest1 $sign(a) = a/|a|$.

Comment: aha..! that was a silly comment from me.. thank you.. i think it will do.. thanks a ton again..

Comment: there is one boundary case problem with this formula namely when $a = a^- = .5$. can we fix that ?